# ASP.NET MVC Project Template don't adjust to 100% on Mobile

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I can't find out why the default template on a Web .Net MVC project is not adjusting to 100% width in a mobile device.

[image]

I use a DataTable on the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<iziConference.Models.EventAttendee>

<h2>Participantes.</h2>
<br />
<button><a style="text-decoration: none" href='@Url.Action("Create", new { eventId = ViewBag.EventId })'>Criar Participante</a></button>
<button id="at-btn-refresh"> Actualizar</button>
<input id="eventId" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.EventId">
<table id="at-attendees-list" cellpadding="10" border="1" class="row-border stripe">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Estado  </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr id="at-line-@item.Attendee_Id">
                <td style="padding: 5px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Attendee.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AttendeeType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Attendee.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Attendee.Email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.IsActive)
                    {
                        <button id="at-active-status-@item.Attendee_Id" class="at-btn-active-state active" data-attendee-id="@item.Attendee_Id" data-attendee-name="@item.Attendee.Name" data-active-new-state="false" data-show-confirmation-alert="true">Desactivar</button>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <button id="at-active-status-@item.Attendee_Id" class="at-btn-active-state inactive" data-attendee-id="@item.Attendee_Id" data-attendee-name="@item.Attendee.Name" data-active-new-state="true" data-show-confirmation-alert="true">Activar</button>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Loaded by script:

```
var _atteendeesList = "at-attendees-list";

 $("#" + _atteendeesList).DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "language": {
        "search": "Pesquisar:",
        "info": "Participantes inscritos: _PAGES_"
    }
 });
```

Using the default _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>izigo Conference - Gestor de Conteúdos</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <section id="login">
                @Html.Partial(MVC.Account.Views._LoginPartial)
            </section>
            <div style="padding: 10px;">
                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", MVC.Home.Index())</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Participantes", MVC.Attendee.Index())</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Check-in", MVC.Checkin.Index())</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer style="padding-left: 25px;">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - <a href="https://www.izigo.pt/conference" target="_blank">izigo Conference</a> - <i>Powered by</i><a href="https://www.izigo.pt" target="_blank">izigo.pt</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/iziconference")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with how to examine CSS styling in the DOM explorer of your browser's debugging tools, now is a great time to start.  When navigating the DOM explorer (at least in Chrome), you can examine any given element and observe the CSS being applied to that element, how it's calculated, how it's nested in its containing element, etc.  This can help you narrow down the styling issue(s), test modifications to the styling, etc.  If you can provide a [mcve] of the HTML/CSS which demonstrates the specific issue, we can help identify it as well.

Comment: Note that the `cellpadding` and `border` attributes on the `table` element were deprecated back in HTML 4.01.

Comment: @David Thank You for your comment and help. I have done that and I can't find anything that help me "pushing" the header to 100%. I have checked and done all the testing and nothing works, only setting a fixed width that pushes the element. I suspect that it's related width long content on the DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching the options of the dataTables library, I was able to find an option to create a responsive solution:

[image]

I have included the options responsive to the construction of the table and the columnDefs to choose which ones to remain visible in the mobile:

```
$("#" + _atteendeesList).DataTable({
"responsive": true,
"columnDefs": [
    { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
    { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -1 }
    ],
"paging": false,
"info": false,
"language": {
    "search": "Pesquisar:",
    "info": "Participantes inscritos: _PAGES_"
    }
});
```

I also had to include in the Bundle the reponsive libraries for js and css of the datatables extensions (download available here: https://datatables.net/download/):

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/iziconference").Include(
                    "~/Content/Scripts/datatables.min.js",
                    "~/Content/Scripts/dataTables.responsive.min.js")); // add-on


            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/Styles/datatables.min.css",
                    "~/Content/Styles/responsive.dataTables.min.css"));
```